# Unable to upload bigger file in mvc5 web.config changes also not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to upload bigger files it shows error

[image]

I have also tried this

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

My IIS version is 10 express and Visual 2017 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Could you try increasing the request limit in IIS?

- goto IIS
- select your site on the left
- double click Request Filtering
- on the right side click Edit Feature Settings...
- increase the maximum allowed content length (Bytes)

In general I would suggest though to upload your files in chunks instead of increasing the upload size.

Comment: I am saving a file in folder and link of image in database . I am not uploading file directly to database that's why I am not using chunks.

Comment: goto iis means from visual studio iis settings ?

Comment: No I mend opening IIS Manager then select your site there.

Comment: Are you hosting this on Azure?  If so, you'll need to manually modify the web.config file through Server Explorer tab

Comment: @PaulHieltjes in IIS manager my site is not showing just Default web site is showing

Comment: @JasonRoner I did not  host yet but I will host it in Azure . what can I do for test ?